# Carregar imagem de DataGrid para Image

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, image

A variável x está associada a uma imagem (campo blob) que carreguei numa Datagrid a partir de uma base de dados MySQL.

```
DataRowView selectedRecord = (DataRowView)dataGridImagem.SelectedItem;
var x= selectedRecord.Row.ItemArray[2];
```

Como posso agora proceder de forma a carregar a imagem para um controlo Image?

Comment: x é do tipo `byte[]`?

Comment: Suponho que sim!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O campo blob provavelmente é representado como `byte[]` no C#. Assumindo isso, você consegue criar a imagem na memória com objeto `BitmapImage` e então atribuir ao Source do mesmo.

```
// assumindo que ItemArray[2] é um array de bytes, faça um cast
var bytes = selectedRecord.Row.ItemArray[2] as byte[];

// crie uma memory-stream com os bytes vindo do banco de dados
var mStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

//cria e manipula o objeto do tipo BitmapImage
var image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.StreamSource = mStream;
image.EndInit();

// atribui para a propriedade Source do controle Image o objeto criado
imageControl.Source = image;
```

Comment: Esta linha lança uma exceção: var mStream = new MemoryStream(bytes); Additional information: A memória intermédia não pode ser nula.

Comment: Então provável que a linha de cima retornou nulo. selectedRecord.Row.ItemArray[2] deve ser de outro tipo.

Comment: E como é que posso verificar isso? Temos algum comando que me permita ver o tipo retornado pelo comando acima?

Comment: Você pode tentar var x= selectedRecord.Row.ItemArray[2]; x.GetType().ToString(). Ou coloque um breakpoint, e passe o cursor sobre x, que deve mostrar o tipo de x.

Comment: Erro meu ... era selectedRecord.Row.ItemArray[1]. Tinha o índice errado. Funciona perfeitamente.